# Django annotate() is not adding up the number of entries but is instead repeating them

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

**Background:**

The Amazon Kindle PaperWhite stores the words we lookup while reading into a sqlite3 database called `vocab.db`. I am working on a small kindle companion app that takes this db file and imports it into a django table for various processing. I have done this step already.

**What I would like to do:**

I would like to query my table `KindleLookups` for my *most difficult words* (ex: how many times have I looked up a specific word). I would ultimately like to present this data in a table ordered by highest count.

**Desired Result:**

| Word | Lookup Count |
| --- | --- |
| Reverberated | 3 |
| Troubadour | 1 |
| Corrugated | 1 |

**My result (undesired):**

Here `Reverberated` is being repeated three times each with a lookup count of one, instead of one time with three lookup count.

| Word | Lookup Count |
| --- | --- |
| Reverberated | 1 |
| Reverberated | 1 |
| Reverberated | 1 |
| Troubadour | 1 |
| Corrugated | 1 |

Model:

```
class KindleLookups(TimeStampedModel):
    book = models.ForeignKey(KindleBookInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.ForeignKey(KindleWords, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class KindleWords(TimeStampedModel):
    word_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

I am trying to accomplish this using [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), but this is repeating the rows instead of adding them up for some reason.

```
context['lookup_counts'] = KindleLookups.objects.annotate(word_count=Count("word"))
```

I then thought that I needed to annotate on the actual word, but nothing seems to have changed.

```
context['lookup_counts'] = KindleLookups.objects.annotate(word_count=Count("word__word"))
```

Template:

```
<tbody>
{% for word in lookup_counts %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ word.word }}</td>
    <td>{{ word.word_count }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

So I am hoping you can answer my questions:

**Questions**

1. What is actually happening with my annotate()? Why is it repeating the rows instead of counting them, despite me using Count()?
2. Would counting on the "word" and "word__word" be the exact same thing?
3. Could this issue be somehow related with my `KindleLookups`'s `__str__` method returning the `self.usage` (the sentence the word was found in) and not the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should annotate the `KindleWords` model instead, so:

```
context['lookup_counts'] = KindleWords.objects.annotate(
    word_count=Count('kindlelookups')
)
```

The `KindleWords`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.word_count` that determines how many times that `KindleWords` is used in the `KindleLookups`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `KindleWord` instead of <s>`KindleWords`</s>.